# Get cURL command line given PHP cURL code

Tags: php, curl

Given a PHP source code with curl handle, how do I get the command line version of that curl request?

Comment: You can get the reversed by using "curl --libcurl example.c [the rest]" to see what libcurl options certain command line options make. That might be a bit helpful at least.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the cURL documentation here:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

or, go to your terminal and type:

```
man curl
```

After reading the documentation, you will have to manually find out which commands map to which functions to get the results you want.  Unlikely to be any easier way to do this.

A lot of it will be just looking at which of PHP's `curl_setopt()` parameters map to the matching command line parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You could just create a php file with the curl command in it, and then just run the php script from the command line.

```
hostname$   php curldownload.php
```

Or, you could have a look here for examples: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/curl-examples/